# Retrieving One's Roster contact list on Login

Tags: cordova, xmpp, chat, strophe

I use strophe.js library to send and receive XMPP messages in browser.

I need to get the list of all the users added(authorized/subscribed)to my roster. How can I achieve this using strophe.js?  I want to show all the users(authorized/subscribed) as friend list of roster.

Comment: Did this solve your question? Please mark as answered if so, otherwise provide more information.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Are you trying to implement IMS One Roster?

Answer (score 1):

Use the roster plugin and call get. With your callback function evaluate the data and manage accordingly.

```
connection.roster.get(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the "**Groupie**" example client app from Chapter-8 of the book
"Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery".

**Groupie** : Group Chatting, A Multi-User Chat Client
See [Index of sample applications](https://github.com/metajack/profxmpp).